# Show that the group $SO_3$ has infinitely many non-Abelian subgroups

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I have just shown that $SO_3$ acts transitively on the unit sphere, and that there is an order-$n$ subgroup for all positive integers $n$.

I'm looking for a hint with where to start to find the construction of infinitely many non-Abelian subgroups?

Comment: Consider a regular polygon inscribed in a maximum circle of the sphere.

Comment: I’m thinking for a given $n$ we could have the subgroup generated by the $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ rotation about the $y$-axis say, and the $\pi$ rotation about the $z$-axis say. Proving that the two given elements don’t commute is simple enough but I would then need to show that each subgroup is distinct, which would be easiest if I could find a general form for the subgroup for each $n$

Comment: That should also work. What I was suggesting is to consider the symmetries of the regular $n$-gon, which is a dihedral group and realize each by the corresponding rotation of the sphere in which the $n$-gon is inscribed.

Comment: If the $n$-gon sits in the $xz$-plane wouldn't the subgroup I mentioned in my comment be isomorphic to $D_{2n}$?

Comment: Yes. I had not really read your comment carefully. I had not seen that you said only a rotation of $\pi$ around the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue by  cardinality, as $SO(3)$ is not enumerable nor abelian. One can construct by induction a strictly increasing sequence $G_n<G_{n+1}$ of non abelian subgroups.

For $G_1$, consider the subgroup generated by 2 non commuting rotations (eg two rotation of angle $\pi \over 100$ with different axis), so that they do not commute.
Assume $G_n$ is constructed. As it is enumerable, there exists a rotation $g_{n}\notin G_n$. Let $G_{n+1}$ the subgroup generated by $g_n$ and $G_n$.